# PyInstaller .exe does nothing

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a complex script into an exe with PyInstaller, this is the install command I am currently using although I have tried many variations of these flags:
`pyinstaller -w -F  --debug=all --noupx --name godnesssakes .\uhoh.py`

When I run the exe from the command line I get no output whatsoever, even with debug mode enabled:
[image]

Even after simplifying my python script to a simple print command I am still getting no output:

```
def main():
    print('test')

main()
```

I have tried everything including reinstalling python, reinstalling pip, verifying path, verifying no conflicting versions, using --path flag in pyinstaller...

Versions:

- Python 3.9.9
- Pyinstaller 5.4.1

Answers that have NOT helped:

- [Pyinstaller, .exe file does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924584/pyinstaller-exe-file-does-nothing)
- [Pyinstaller EXE file does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851492/pyinstaller-exe-file-does-nothing)
- [Pyinstaller generating EXE that does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681974/pyinstaller-generating-exe-that-does-nothing)
- [PyInstaller .exe file does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592827/pyinstaller-exe-file-does-nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow each of these steps... or use your operating system's equvalent.

1. `mkdir newdir` and `cd newdir`
2. `py -m venv venv` and `venv\Scripts\activate`
3. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller`
4. copy your script into the `newdir/main.py`

To make it even more obvious:....

```
def main():
    while True:
        print('test', end='\r')

main()
```

5. `pyinstaller -F --debug=all --noupx --name goodnesssakes main.py`
6. `dist\goodnesssakes.exe`

---

The actual problem is that you are using the `-w` flag which tells pyinstaller that it is a windowed application and therefore doesn't output anything to the console. It is literally and alias for `--noconsole`